# Parse.com listening for log out event

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am working on an ios app using parse as a backend.

I am having an issue where i am putting all of my save calls into a queue when i am offline and then using reachability's "kReachabilityChangedNotification" to trigger them as soon as they come online.

This usually works very well and is, for the most part, more preferable to parse's saveEventually function. However, it runs into trouble when the user is logged out before they come back online causing the save call to fail as we check for users in the before save.

So i was wondering if anyone had any ideas for how to listen for when the user is logged in/out, so i can also trigger the queue based on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check that currentUser is not null on the Client side, before the save. Also , if the user logs in and out via the app you can do that logic there.

Comment: Do you mean check the current user before it is put in the queue? or before it is executed once the queue is triggered?

Comment: I could put the logic in when they log in/out. Although i have also had reports of people being randomly logged out which is a concern.

Comment: Both at queuing and at execution.

Comment: I think you've got it